# How to do a keyword search and list the keywords present in selected column to a new column for a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a df which has a column foodhist

It can include `'cheeseburgers,largepizzafrompizzahut'` as enteries

`df['foodhist']`

And i have a list `unhealthyfoods = ['burger','pizza' etc.]`

I want to add
`df['unhealthyfoodyouhad']` column which will look for all the items from `unhealthyfoods` in `df['foodhist']` and add them to this column.

The data in `df['foodhist']` can be not spaced, not separated but I still want to look for appearance of the keywords and return them in the `df['unhealthyfoodyouhad']`.

for this in 'cheeseburgers,largepizzafrompizzahut' in it should add burger,pizza in the `df['unhealthyfoodyouhad']` column.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import re

unhealthyfoods=['burger','pizza']

df=pd.DataFrame({'foodhist':['cheeseburger','burgerandlargepizza']})
list1=[]
for food in unhealthyfoods:
    list1.append([re.findall(food,x) for x in df['foodhist']])
df['unhealthyfoodyouhad']=pd.DataFrame(list1).T.sum(1)
df['unhealthyfoodyouhad']=[','.join(i) for i in df['unhealthyfoodyouhad']]
```

output:

```
df
Out[95]: 
              foodhist unhealthyfoodyouhad
0         cheeseburger              burger
1  burgerandlargepizza        burger,pizza
```